# Redirect output in two different files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am recording output of my script in a 2 different files, Dailydata.txt and historicData.txt.
I was hoping that I need to just `stdout` in 2 different files like below,

```
sys.stdout = open('historicData.txt', 'a+')
sys.stdout = open('Dailydata.txt', 'r+')
```

But, it directs output to one file only.

So I redirected my output to `DailyData.txt` first and then write it in `HistoricData.txt`

```
        with open(file_path + 'HistoricDaily.txt', 'r') as fread, open(file_path + 'FidelityHistoric.txt', 'a+') as fwrite:
            fread_lines = fread.readlines()
            for i in fread_lines:
                fwrite.write(i)
```

What happens here is, every time I run the script, it writes the current run number
say `HistoricData.txt` contains `1 2 3 4` and `DailyData.txt` contains `5`.
When I run my script, `DailyData.txt` will contain `6`, it instead of copying the `6`, script copies `5`. If I run it again, it will copy `6` and not `7`.

My script is like,

```
class MyClass:

    stdout = open('historicData.txt', 'a+')
try:
# my code Selenium stuff


except:
# my code

finally:
     # copy data to HistoricData here
```

What I am trying to achieve here is script should copy the same data from `DailyData` in `HistoricData`

Redirect the data in 2 different files at the same time.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to use the `logging` module https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html

You can create two appenders (one per file) and a logging format that suits your needs.

Monkey patching `sys.stdout` is a hacky way to achieve what you can do with the proper classes already included in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly you are trying to write some data to a file(`Dailydata.txt`), copy it on another(`historicData.txt`) then at the second iteration you would like `Dailydata.txt` to be rewritten with the new data and add the new data at the and of `historicData.txt`.

You can try this:

```
with open('Dailydata.txt', 'rb') as r:
    with open('historicData.txt', 'ab') as w:
        lines = r.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            w.write(str(line))
```

If you, instead, want to write the same data at the same time in both files you just have to explicitly do so:

```
def my_data_generator():
   #do stuff

def my_writer():
   daily = open('Dailydata.txt', 'w')
   historic = open('historicData.txt', 'ab')
   data = my_data_generator()
   daily.write(data)
   historic.write(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is redirect the data into 2 different files. I can't `stdout` data in 2 different files at the same time. So, what I am doing is, I redirect data in `DailyData` first then write it into `HistoricData`.  Now things get tricky here. Lets say I ran the script for the first time and  outputted 1 in in `DailyData` but my write code(as above) does not copy 1 into `HistoricData`. When I ran the script 2nd time, it writes `2` in `DailyData` and `1` in `HistoricData`. If I run it 3rd time, it will copy 3 in DD and 2 in HD and so on. HD shld hv same data as DD

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, instead of saving the data directly on file you should store it in a variable then write the data in both files.